# Text artifacts in Magic Online .dat file when decoding as ANSI (Windows 1252)

Tags: encoding, character-encoding

The game "Magic the Gathering Online" saves its log files as .dat files, which can be read by opening them with notepad, which reads them with ANSI encoding (Windows machine, so I assume Windows 1252 encoding)

Most of the file is as expected, but there are some weird artifacts before every action. I assume this is information that wasn't meant to be encoded as text, maybe a timestamp. I tried opening the file in Python using `open` and different encodings, but none except for ANSI worked.

I'd like to recover and/or understand what was encoded here, but have no idea how to go about this.

Here is an excerpt (note that @P is some sort of delimiter and doesn't change throughout the entire file)

```
þ++‹ Ú @PJackomatrus rolled a 2.
þ++‹ Ú @PNateWindgrace rolled a 4.
‘?+‹ Ú  @P@PJackomatrus joined the game.
]+‹ Ú "@P@PNateWindgrace joined the game.
ÏHí-‹ Ú &@PNateWindgrace chooses to play first.
»_ù0‹ Ú '@PNateWindgrace mulligans to six cards.
```

Comment: I'd guess that it's a _binary_ file where a few leading bytes could contain e.g. a timestamp (and more info?).

Comment: @JosefZ how would I go about trying to decode this without any information about the quality of data? Is this just hopeless without any additional info?